# Failed SMTP Authentication - TOSHIBA e-STUDIO255

Tags: email, network-printer, smtp-auth, user-settings, mailscanner

I do have TOSHIBA e-STUDIO255 and i have configured scan to email option. about one week it's worked perfectly but now it's keep giving me this error "Failed SMTP Authentication". i have not change any settings on printer. smtp settings as follows.

SMTP client:

```
Enable SMTP Client              : Enable  
Enable SSL                      : Accept all certificates without CA  
SSL/TLS                         : STARTTLS  
SMTP Server Address             : smtp.gmail.com  
POP Before SMTP                 : Disable  
Authentication                  : Login  
Login Name                      : abc@gmail.com  
Maximum Email / InternetFax Size: 30 MB  
Port Number                     : 25  
SMTP Client Connection Timeout(1-180) : 30 Seconds
```

SMTP server:

```
Enable SMTP Server    : Enable  
Port Number           : 25  
Email Address         : fax@testdomain.com  
Enable OffRamp Gateway: Disable  
OffRamp Security     : Enable  
OffRamp Print        : Enable
```

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Since you don't have access to gmail.com logs, I would suggest two things. First, log to gmail.com account (abc@gmail.com), look for any mailbox quota warnings, change your password and update password in Toshiba smtp client settings. If that doesn't help, use different account for authentication, it can be another gmail.com address or better, email on different domain. If that doesn't produce results, contact Toshiba support and let them check for issues on device itself.

Comment: seeing as there is supporting info as to why this could be an issue, I'm not sure why it was downvoted. http://googleappsupdates.blogspot.ro/2016/05/disabling-support-for-sslv3-and-rc4-for.html

Answer (score 1):

In my experiance with toshibas/any copier, you should setup a local MTA (postfix on a vm, raspberry pi, whatever), use the [pi as a smarthost relay to gmai](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/configure-postfix-to-use-gmail-as-a-mail-relay/)l,

Another option is to put them behind the print server (no idea how your network is setup) and install smtp relay on the windows server (iis smtp work but others exist).

If PCI/HIPPA is involved you likely need that unit upgraded or replaced to scan PIAA over your network since only TLSv1.1 and 1.2 satisfy their latest desires.

But this is why it doesn't work: 
[http://www.infoworld.com/article/3071171/security/google-to-shutter-sslv3-rc4-from-smtp-servers-gmail.html](http://google-to-shutter-sslv3-rc4-from-smtp-servers)

This is why the company I worked for built an email server just for the copiers they sold.

**SMTP Server or Client**

you should use one or the other, either be your own MTA and send email (which might make it an open relay on your localsubnet) or be a client, I would suggest client and the postfix relay option.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if "Failed SMTP Authentication" equates to *Unable to connect to server* (perhaps, the software doesn't distinguish between the two issues). It's not uncommon for ISPs to block outbound SMTP traffic, unless you're a business user. Maybe there was a recent change on their end in regards to policy. I would recommend running `telnet smtp.gmail.com 25` and examining the output. If you're unable to connect, that is likely the cause of the issue.

Comment: good point, he shouldn't be using 25 for client connections, it should be 587.